# Changing file association for an extension not in a list

Tags: windows-xp

Here's the thing.

There is an  Autocad script file, extension ***.scr***  which by default opens in Notepad. It is a regular text file, in which I need to do some edits so I want it to open in Vim.

Upon going to Windows Explorer / Tools / .... / that list of file extensions, I see that it's not there (?!).

Not under ***.scr***, not under anything remotely similar to Autocad, Autodesk, ... anything.

***So I'd like to know, where could it be and how can I change it to Vim for the default open association?***

*Any clues?*

Edit: Also, when I right click on it in Windows Explorer, there is no *Open With ...* option, so no luck there. Completely dumbfounded here.

Edit2: Solved the problem. Deleted everything related (and remotely related) to ***.scr*** in Registry, and it defaulted back to gvim, as my text editor. Don't know what caused it, nor what exactly fixed it. Nothing seemed to be associated with .scr in Registry, nor anything similar.

If anyone knows something about this, put it down as an answer.

Comment: scr by default is also associated with the windows screensaver, this may be the reason you had problems.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Deleted everything related (and remotely related) to .scr in Registry, and it defaulted back to gvim, as my text editor. Don't know what caused it, nor what exactly fixed it. Nothing seemed to be associated with .scr in Registry, nor anything similar.

If anyone knows something about this, put it down as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the file and click on properties.
2. There should be a section that says "Opens with:".  Click on the "Change..." button.
3. Select the application you want.  If it is not in the list, click on the "Browse..." button and find the application in your directory.

Comment: Nope. No such option.

Comment: Ah didn't notice you were on XP sorry.